# How to trigger Jenkins builds remotely using URL with parameters

Tags: jenkins

I'm trying to trigger build in Jenkins remotely using URL.
the URL is : "http://myJenkinsURL/job/myProjectName/build?token=SOME_TOKEN&EXTID=lkjsdfljsdflkjsdfjklsdflkj"

The problem is when i try to trigger this build it redirect me to my Jenkins and ask me to insert the parameter but i already passed it over the URL.

Is there something that I'm missing in the process?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

https://wiki.jenkins.io/display/JENKINS/Parameterized+Build has the gory, but it mentions that you want a URL like this (note buildWithParameters):

http://server/job/myjob/buildWithParameters?token=TOKEN&PARAMETER=Value

so your call might look like this:

```
curl -X POST "http://myJenkinsURL/job/myProjectName/buildWithParameters?token=SOME_TOKEN&EXTID=lkjsdfljsdflkjsdfjklsdflkj"
```

Comment: I was trying it but I couldn't pass the parameters but this solved my problem, thank you.